# Remove the line that found in array while processes a code PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following code which getting some links from remote.
Now the code while processesing and found the hash [if($done==true)] keep sending request to the host even if the hash have been found in the link.

i need the code stop sending requests to the host that we found its hash, and keep working on the other hosts, so it will be exclude all founded hosts from the the second foreach [foreach (file("hosts.txt")] and not send more request to them.

please if any one can help to fix my code .

sorry about bad english.

```
$MAXPROCESS=50;
$execute=0;
$Arr = array();
foreach (file("hashes.txt") as $hashkey => $hash) 
{
$hash = trim($hash);
$pid = pcntl_fork();
$execute++;
if ($execute >= $MAXPROCESS)
{
    while (pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) 
    {
        $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
        $execute =0;
        //sleep(1);
        flush();
        //echo " [$ipkey]  Child $status completed\n";
    }
}

if (!$pid) 
{

    foreach (file("hosts.txt") as $hostkey => $hosts) 
    {
        $host = trim($hosts);

        if(!in_array($host,$Arr))
        {
            $done = CHECK_URL($host.$hash.'.xml');
            if($done==true)
            {
                    $Arr[] = $host;
                echo "\n\r\n\r".$host." : Found [$hashkey]         ------------\n\r\n\r";
            }else{
                echo $host." : error [$hashkey]\n";
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        flush();
    }
exit;
}
}

function CHECK_URL($url)
{

    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5 );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$response = curl_getinfo($ch);
//if($response['http_code']=="200" || preg_match('/xml/i', $result))
if($response['http_code']=="200")
{
    file_put_contents('hash.found.txt', $url."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    return true;
}
curl_close($ch); // Close the curl stream
}
.............................
```

Comment: can you post a relevant, short sample of hashes.txt?

Comment: Your function `CHECK_URL()` doesn't actually return anything, which means that `$done` will always be `null` and never `true`.

Comment: i have add the full CHECK_URL function in the code.
now is the code is full.

Comment: Looks like filling `$Arr` with the contents of `hash.found.txt` before looping through `hosts.txt` will do the trick, or am I missing something?

Comment: how could it be ?
could you do it please.

Comment: @Jeff here is the hashes 
    r2llnd4hy0
pfr1bgf8eh
a8vk1fptii
1o16kr76g2
raxyd97n03
yyotyefuak
h8m0ipfn4e
wyq6ea9hfd